# ember.js - is it possible to use jQuery 2.x?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm currently writing an mobile web app for Android/iOS with ember.js and therefore don't need to support old IE versions. Is it possible to use ember.js (1.2.0) with the latest jQuery 2.x build? I'd like to do this because I've read jQuery 1.x is quite a bit slower compared to 2.x, so I'd like to benefit form the speedup in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: YES

At work I'm currently using Ember 1.2.0, Handlebars: 1.1.2 and jQuery 2.0.3. All thanks to bower. No issues at all.

More information on the differences between jQuery 1 and 2 can be found on the [jQuery blog announcement post](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

As fas as I know the only differences between jQuery 2.x and the 1.x versions is that 2.x versions are smaller and faster thanks to the fact it doesn't need to support older browsers.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check it as soon as possible, and if it works fine accept the answer or will amend it with what I've found!